# Issue to start another activity after facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

If anyone can help me start another activity after checking Facebook login in my Android app, I already try to put in different parts of the code an intention and nothing could help after that.

I have tried putting the intent in the onSucces () method but it still doesn't work.

I leave my code below.

```
class principio : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var LoginButton: LoginButton
lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
lateinit var fotoPerfil: ImageView
lateinit var Profile: Profile;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principio)


    LoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button)
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    LoginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    fotoPerfil = findViewById(R.id.Bienvenida)



    LoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@principio,"se obtuvo  el resultado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            saltarActividad()
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            Snackbar.make(root_layout,"se Activo en el OnCANCEL",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })


}// final del onCreate


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    saltarActividad()
     Snackbar.make(root_layout,"se Activo en el On Activity",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

}

var tokenTracker: AccessTokenTracker = object : AccessTokenTracker() {
    override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(oldAccessToken: AccessToken?, currentAccessToken: AccessToken?) {
        if (currentAccessToken == null) {
          saltarActividad()
            fotoPerfil.setImageResource(0)
            Toast.makeText(this@principio, "User Logget Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        } else {
            loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken)

        }

    }

}

fun loadUserProfile(newAccesToken: AccessToken) {
    var parametros = Bundle()
    var Activity2 = saltarActividad()

    var GraphRequest: GraphRequest =
        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccesToken, object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {
            override fun onCompleted(`object`: JSONObject?, response: GraphResponse?) {

                var first_name: String = `object`!!.getString("first_name")
                var last_name: String = `object`.getString("last_name")
                var email: String = `object`.getString("email")
                var id: String = `object`.getString("id")
                var image_url: String =
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "picture?type=normal"


                Toast.makeText(this@principio,"se quedo aqui",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Glide.with(this@principio).load(image_url).into(fotoPerfil)
                fotoPerfil.buildDrawingCache()
                var bitmap = fotoPerfil.drawingCache
                Activity2.putExtra("first_name", first_name)
                Activity2.putExtra("last_name", last_name)
                Activity2.putExtra("email", email)
                Activity2.putExtra("BitImage", bitmap)
                startActivity(Activity2);

            }


        })
    parametros.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id")
    GraphRequest.parameters = parametros
    startActivity(Activity2);
    GraphRequest.executeAsync()





}

private fun saltarActividad(): Intent {
    var Activity2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    return Activity2
}
```

}

no error appears in my logcat, everything runs perfect. only the other activity does not start, someone who has been able to deal with this problem and has solved it?

I leave a small photo of where my code gets stuck.
[Here it gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s9QC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are some reasons cause the problem could be raise, so in order to solve it, lets begin with the app configuration on Facebook developers page.

This is the documentation where you can find all the steps you need to do to register your app for facebook development.

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/?locale=es_ES**

First, you need to create an application on the page, giving it a name (it should not be the same as your real application name, but by convention, put something similar)

Once you created it, add to your gradle dependencies the Facebook SDK implementation and sync your project:

**implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'**

Then, on step four, facebook will give you some code to make the configuration for your app:

[image]

The first one, are just strings which you have to add to your strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Facebook</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">688207335076511</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb688207335076511</string>

</resources>
```

**NOTE: the values of those strings will be different to your app, just copy the code snippet that facebook developers page give it to you.**

The second one is to add Internet Permissions to your app on your manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And finally, add some metadata which facebook requires to connect your android app with the registration you made on the page.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The step 5, ask you for the package name of your application, if you are on development, you can just ignore this step.

Also you will need to register a keyhash from your android app. In order to get this,
you can follow the steps the page give you or well, I will leave you this code snippet, change the package name string with yours and put it inside your onCreate method and run the app, the hashkey will appear on your logcat.

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(

                    "yourPackageName",

                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

So, if you followed all these steps correctly, you are ready to start coding the logic of your app. Use this as a guide:

```
package com.example.facebook;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.facebook.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    //Facebook components
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button facebookLogin;
    LoginManager loginManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        configFacebookLogin();    //Facebook Login Configuration
    }

    private void configFacebookLogin() {

        //First, init a callbackManager and a loginManager instances.
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        //Then, pass that callback to your loginManager instance via registerCallBack method as you see
        //below
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("FacebookCallback", "onSuccess: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("FacebookCallback", "onSuccess: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("FacebookCallback", "onSuccess: ");

            }
        });

        //bind your button to your xml button and set an onClick method to it
        facebookLogin = binding.buttonFacebookLogin;
        facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //With this line, you trigger the facebook login.
                loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
            }
        });

    }

    //Also, you need to add the callbackManager.onActivityResult method to pass the token
    //of you facebook session to the loginManager, so your app will know if your login succeed or failed.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Other things that I see are you aren't using the startActivity() method to start your intent, so fix that too. And for last, delete all those intents (saltarActividad()) that
are not in onSuccess() method (which is the right place).

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun saltarActividad(): Intent { // returning an intent
   var Activity2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
   return Activity2
}
```

This method only returns an intent, so calling this wouldn't start the main activity. You need to pass this method to `startActivity()` like

```
startActivity(saltarActividad())
```

The problem is in your `onActivityResult`.

Try this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    startActivity(saltarActividad()) // the issue was here

    Snackbar.make(root_layout,"se Activo en el On Activity",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: I've already tried, and still don't want to jump to Main Activity :(